# Constrain mouse movement to region in OS X without jitter

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics, osx-elcapitan, hid

I would like to constrain mouse movement to a specific rectangular region of the screen in OS X 10.11. I modified some code from [MouseTools](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112011027/http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html) (below) to do this but it's jittery when you hit the edge of the screen. How can I get rid of this jitter?

```
// gcc -Wall constrain.cpp -framework ApplicationServices -o constrain

#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    if(argc != 5) {
        printf("Usage: constrain left top right bottom\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int leftBound = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    int topBound = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);
    int rightBound = strtol(argv[3], NULL, 10);
    int bottomBound = strtol(argv[4], NULL, 10);
    CGEventTapLocation tapLocation = kCGHIDEventTap;
    CGEventSourceRef sourceRef = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStatePrivate);
    while(true) {
        CGEventRef mouseEvent = CGEventCreate(NULL);
        CGPoint mouseLoc = CGEventGetLocation(mouseEvent);
        int x = mouseLoc.x, y = mouseLoc.y;
        if(x < leftBound || x > rightBound || y < topBound || y > bottomBound) {
            if(x < leftBound) x = leftBound;
            if(x > rightBound) x = rightBound;
            if(y < topBound) y = topBound;
            if(y > bottomBound) y = bottomBound;
            CGEventRef moveMouse = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(sourceRef, kCGEventMouseMoved, CGPointMake(x, y), 0);
            CGEventPost(tapLocation, moveMouse);
            CFRelease(moveMouse);
        }
        CFRelease(mouseEvent);
        usleep(8*1000); // 8ms, ~120fps
    }
    CFRelease(sourceRef);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are some other things I tried: [Receiving, Filtering, and Modifying Mouse Events](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103161752/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter2/altermouse/) shows how to create a callback for mouse movements using `CGEventTapCreate`. In the code it says "We can change aspects of the mouse event. For example, we can use `CGEventSetLocation(event, newLocation)`." Unfortunately this doesn't actually change the mouse location (complete example [here](https://gist.github.com/kylemcdonald/3f4abf55e718f6e80fd2335c5ac077cc)). The only ways I've been able to change the mouse location are by doing a `CGEventPost` or `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition`. I also tried using  `kCGHIDEventTap` instead of `kCGSessionEventTap`, and I checked that I had super user permissions and accessibility enabled for the app. It seems like it should work because there is another example of [modifying key presses](https://web.archive.org/web/20200503003001/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter2/alterkeys/) which works correctly. Instead of using `CGEventSetLocation` I also tried using `CGEventSetIntegerValueField` (like in the keyboard example) to set the x and y deltas to 0, but this didn't change anything.

Finally, I also tried using `CGEventPost` and `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition` inside the `CGEventCallback`, the "invisible border" still it is more jittery than the above code.

Comment: The description of your issue is verbose.  Nobody cares about what you have done with an AppleScript program unless you have an issue with it.

Comment: @ElTomato I made the issue less verbose by removing the two sentences explaining my first attempt with AppleScript and the issue I had with it. Assuming you know anything about this topic, I'd love to have your feedback on the updated question. Thanks!

Comment: Whose mouse movement is going to be contrainted?  Anyone using your computer or the user of your application?

Comment: @ElTomato this is for a public screen where I'm trying to restrict movement on a touchscreen to a specific region. But the application in the foreground is actually Chrome. So I think "anyone using your computer" is the answer.

Comment: An aside, the solution I found (finally) for completely disabling the menu bar (and Dock) in Chrome is to add `LSUIPresentationMode` with mode `3` to Chrome's `Info.plist`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've implemented this for Wine in the Mac driver. It gets a bit complicated.

The approach is to basically disable movement of the mouse cursor by calling `CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(false)`. This right here achieves what you want if the constraining rectangle is the 1x1 rect at the cursor's current location.

On top of that, I then use an event tap to observe the mouse move events. These don't change position but have the deltas of what the user attempted to do. I then use `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition()` to move the cursor according to those deltas and adjust the events before passing them along.

Note that the location information in the mouse events is not meaningful. It will be stale. Some of the events will have been queued before your last warp and so have an old location. You need to track where the cursor is yourself. It starts wherever it was when you disassociated it from the mouse and changes whenever you warp it. You add the deltas to that (not to the event location), clip that to the constraining rectangle, and use that as the new position for the event and for the warp. For the next event, you'll start from this new position. Etc.

There's an additional unfortunate wrinkle. `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition()` affects the delta values of subsequent mouse move events. Basically, the distance that you warped the cursor is added to the first mouse move event that's queued after the warp. Unchecked, this will effectively double the user's mouse movements with each event for a runaway feedback loop and the cursor will shoot off to one extreme or the other.

So, you have to keep a record of the warps you perform, when you performed them, and how much they changed the position. Then, as events come through the tap, you compare their time to the warp times. For any warps that are earlier than the current event, you subtract out their position change from the event's deltas and remove them from the list.

Comment: Thanks Ken. What you're describing does sound like the best possible solution. And thanks for your work on Wine for Mac!